# How to up-scale an image {PHP}

Tags: php, image-processing

I used the code below to get an image:

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=800x600&zoom=12&center=(10.763705518561297,106.64444580078126)";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

I received a 640px x 640px image meanwhile I expected a 800px x 600px one. How do I scale that image to 800px x 600px?

Comment: See [here on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=resize+images+php&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Firstly, what does `file_get_contents()` have to do with that? That's like asking "How do I do that on rainy afternoons?". Then, if you plan to serve this to a webbrowser, rather make the browser scale the image accordingly, because this way it only costs you CPU time, increases the transmitted data and it may well happen that the browser has to scale the image anyway in order to fit onto whatever display it runs on. Actually, if possible, tell the browser where to find the image at Google's, so that it doesn't make a detour through your webserver first.

Comment: this isn't actually an image, is it, this is a Google Map box, Yes? in which case the PHP pre-render processing (as given in Gauravs answer) would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Here, rescaling is done by 50%, you can change parameter as per your requirement. You can even use Imagick for image manipulation. See, if that helps.

Referred: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php)